# How to Interact between a view component's form and a controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm beginner in web designing with ASP.NET Core. I wrote a view component that has a form with some inputs related to a view model. One of these inputs is a file input (of the `IFormFile` datatype).

I want to submit this view model to an action of a controller (`POST` action), check the validity of model, return another view component if the model state is valid, and remain on this view component with this view model if model state is not valid.

This is my View Model: `PricingViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class PricingViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Select a file")]
    public IFormFile formFile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ColumnCode")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter {0} value, please")]
    public string colCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ColumnName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter {0} value, please")]         
    public string colName { get; set; }
}
```

My View Component (controller): `PricingComponent.cs`

```cs
public class PricingComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(PricingViewModel pricing)
    {               
        return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View("PricingView", pricing));
    }
}
```

My View Component (view): `PricingView.cshtml`

```html
<form class="text-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input name="IsValidPricing" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.isValid" />

   <div class="form-group text-left">
     <label asp-for="colCode" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="colCode" class="form-control" id="colCodeId"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="colCode" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group text-left">
     <label asp-for="colName" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="colName" class="form-control" id="colNameId"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="colName" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group text-left">
     <label asp-for="formFile " class="control-label"></label>
     <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .csv" asp-for="formFile" id="MyInputFile"/>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group mt-4">
     <input type="submit" asp-action="ShowPricing" asp-controller="Home" value="Show" id="ShowPricingBtn" />
   </div>
</form>
```

My Home Controller: `HomeController.cs`

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ShowPricing(PricingViewModel pricing)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int temp;
        if (!int.TryParse(pricing.colCode, out temp))
        {
            ViewBag.isValid = 0;
            ModelState.AddModelError("colCode", "Invalid Data");
            return ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = pricing }); // 1
        }
        else if (!int.TryParse(pricing.colName, out temp))
        {
            ViewBag.isValid = 0;
            ModelState.AddModelError("colName", "Invalid Data");
            return ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = pricing }); //2
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.isValid = 1;   
            
            // do something ...

            return ViewComponent("ShowPricingExcelComponent"); //Call another view component
        }
    }
    else
    {
       ViewBag.isValid = 0;
       return ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = pricing }); //3
    }
}
```

### Plan A

The above approach is my primary plan.

#### Problem

If I use options of submit input tag (`asp-action`, `asp-controller`) like above, the view model sends correctly, but I don't know how to handle the validity of the model and remain on this view component. In the above code, when the `ShowPricing` action runs, if the model state is valid, the code works correctly, but when model is invalid (1,2,3), the `PricingView` doesn't show the validation summery, and just loads with current view model.

### Plan B

I used AJAX to send the `viewModel` to the action and instead of showing the validation summary, I send an alert to the user with AJAX. I changed `PricingView` as following:

My View Component (view): `PricingView.cshtml`

```html
<form class="text-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input name="IsValidPricing" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.isValid" />

   <div class="form-group text-left">
     <label asp-for="colCode" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="colCode" class="form-control" id="colCodeId"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="colCode" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group text-left">
     <label asp-for="colName" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="colName" class="form-control" id="colNameId"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="colName" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group text-left">
     <label asp-for="fromFile " class="control-label"></label>
     <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .csv" asp-for="formFile" id="MyInputFile"/>
   </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ShowPricingBtn').click(function () {
                var _url = '@Url.Action("ShowPricing", "Home")';
                var input = $("#MyInputFile").get(0).files[0]; 

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: _url,
                    data: {
                       formFile: input,
                       colCode: $("#colCode").val(),
                       colName: $("#colName").val(),
                    },
                    success: function (result) 
                    {
                       var IsValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValidPricing"]').val();
                       if (IsValid) 
                       {
                          $("#ShowExcelTable").html(result);
                       }
                       else {
                          alert("Invalid Data");
                       }
                    },
                });
           });
       });
    </script>
   <div class="form-group mt-4">
     <input type="submit" value="Show" id="ShowPricingBtn" />
   </div>
</form>
```

#### Problem

In this code:

1. If the model state is not valid, the alert sends correctly, but
2. If the model state is valid, the `formFile` input doesn't send correctly to action and it's null in view model.

I don't know whether I should go with the original or the alternate approach these problems. Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've checked your code and it's working with validation. Errors are displayed. 

Why you are using ```return ViewComponent(...)``` instead of return ```View(...)```?

Comment: @Justthebenno Which plan did you check? How did you write code that is worked and validation displayed. I used return viewComponent(...) because my view is a viewcomponent (in ~/Views/shared/Components).

Comment: I made some changes like always returning the same ViewComponent ```return ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = pricing }); ``` I wanted to avoid having new components for each case. I build a simple GET method like ```        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ShowPricing() => ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = new PricingViewModel() });``` and send the form.
Result:  https://pasteboard.co/JKkcYTO.png

Comment: For your use-case, a simple view *seems* to be enough. ViewComponents are more for [advanced scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)

Comment: @Justthebenno I don't write all of my project. I just write a part of this. because of rest of my project, I have to use view component, not simple view.

Comment: @Justthebenno Could I want you, write your code in answer part, please? I confused how you could handle validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how do you call view components,here are the working demos:

**For PlanA**

1.Create `ViewComponents/PricingComponent.cs` and `ViewComponents/ShowPricingExcelComponent.cs`.

```
public class PricingComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(PricingViewModel pricing)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View("PricingView", pricing));
    }
}    
public class ShowPricingExcelComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(PricingViewModel pricing)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View("ShowPricingExcel", pricing));
    }
}
```

2.Create `Views/Shared/Components/PricingComponent/PricingView.cshtml`.

```
@model PricingViewModel 
<form class="text-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input name="IsValidPricing" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.isValid" />

    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label asp-for="colCode" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="colCode" class="form-control" id="colCodeId" />
        <span asp-validation-for="colCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label asp-for="colName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="colName" class="form-control" id="colNameId" />
        <span asp-validation-for="colName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label asp-for="formFile " class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .csv" asp-for="formFile" id="MyInputFile" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <input type="submit" asp-action="ShowPricing" asp-controller="Home" value="Show" id="ShowPricingBtn" />
    </div>
</form>
```

3.Create `Views/Shared/Components/ShowPricingExcelComponent/ShowPricingExcel.cshtml`.

```
<h1>Excel....</h1>
```

**Project Structure:**

[image]

4.`Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PricingComponent")
```

5.HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ShowPricing(PricingViewModel pricing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int temp;
            if (!int.TryParse(pricing.colCode, out temp))
            {
                ViewBag.isValid = 0;
                ModelState.AddModelError("colCode", "Invalid Data");
                return View("Index", pricing);
            }
            if (!int.TryParse(pricing.colName, out temp))
            {
                ViewBag.isValid = 0;
                ModelState.AddModelError("colName", "Invalid Data");
                return View("Index", pricing);
            }
            else 
            {
                ViewBag.isValid = 1;

                // do something ...

                return ViewComponent("ShowPricingExcelComponent"); //Call another view component
            }              
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.isValid = 0;
            return View("Index", pricing); //3
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**For PlanB**

1.Create `ViewComponents/PricingComponent.cs` and `ViewComponents/ShowPricingExcelComponent.cs`.

2.Create `Views/Shared/Components/PricingComponent/PricingView.cshtml`.

Firstly,it should be `type="button"` otherwise it will call twice to the backend.Secondly,what you did in ajax is not correct,more detailed explation you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65589490/11398810).At last,you could not judge the modelstate by get the value of `IsValidPricing` value in your sucess function.Because the value you get is always be the data you first render the page,you cannot get the changed ViewBag value when ajax post back.

```
@model PricingViewModel
<form class="text-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input name="IsValidPricing" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.isValid" />

    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label asp-for="colCode" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="colCode" class="form-control" id="colCodeId" />
        <span asp-validation-for="colCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label asp-for="colName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="colName" class="form-control" id="colNameId" />
        <span asp-validation-for="colName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label asp-for="formFile " class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .csv" asp-for="formFile" id="MyInputFile" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mt-4">
        @*it should be type="button"*@
        <input type="button" value="Show" id="ShowPricingBtn" />
    </div>
</form>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ShowPricingBtn').click(function () {
            var _url = '@Url.Action("ShowPricing", "Home")';
            var input = $("#MyInputFile").get(0).files[0];

            var fdata = new FormData();
            fdata.append("formFile", input);
            $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
                fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: _url,
                data: fdata,
                contentType: false,   
                processData: false,
                success: function (result)
                {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result==false)
                    {
                        alert("Invalid Data");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#ShowExcelTable").html(result);

                    }
                },
            });
        });
  });
</script>
```

3.Create `Views/Shared/Components/ShowPricingExcelComponent/ShowPricingExcel.cshtml`.

```
<h1>Excel....</h1>
```

4.`Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PricingComponent")
<div id="ShowExcelTable"></div>
```

5.HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ShowPricing(PricingViewModel pricing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int temp;
            if (!int.TryParse(pricing.colCode, out temp)|| !int.TryParse(pricing.colName, out temp))
            {
                ViewBag.isValid = 0;
                return Json(false);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.isValid = 1;

                // do something ...
                return ViewComponent("ShowPricingExcelComponent"); //Call another view component
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.isValid = 0;
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... I used plan B (ajax) and got answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your error. Your code, as presented, works as expected. A validation message is displayed.

To make it a working example, I've added a GET method first.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ShowPricing() => ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = new PricingViewModel() });
```

Open the URL *Home/ShowPricing*

Fill out the form.

[image]

Send the form. And the validation message is displayed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Did you use my code without change?(except this get mode action)

Comment: There was a typo, I guess, ```else if (!int.TryParse(updatePricing.colName, out temp))``` to ```else if (!int.TryParse(pricing.colName, out temp))``` but yes, your code.

Comment: I added this piece of code ( [HttpGet]
public IActionResult ShowPricing() => ViewComponent("PricingComponent", new { pricing = new PricingViewModel() }); ) to HomeController. but didn't work for me!! Why?

Comment: What I can over you, is to have a Live share session or something similar and I can have a look at your code and we can try to figure out why.

Comment: thanks for your tip about typo. I edited this.

Comment: Could you upload your solution here, please? I review all of your code and find difference. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/just-the-benno/Stackoverflow-Questions-65785939

Comment: I realized why my code with this action worked wrong. because of my rest project, My viewComponent is showed in a part of web page and in the other parts are showed :_sitelayout view and parent view of view component (the view that call my view component). When I use your action (Get mode), My view component is displayed in a single view without his parent and site layout. but validations are displayed correctly.

Comment: If you use site layout, you will see your view component does not display in a right place in web page. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: Yeah. Because it returns a ViewComponent and not a View.

Comment: I guess, I won't find solution via plan A :( ... Probably, I have to use ajax... but ajax can't send my model to action, correctly...

Comment: It is possible. Though, your input file makes it a bit complicated. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903310/uploading-file-using-ajax-in-asp-net-core/49966788) as inspiration. Keep in mind, that you need to add your other properties like ```colCode``` to the form data (```formData.append("colCode", <ValueOfColCode>);```)